Confusion regarding Little oh and Big O notations
This is a conceptual doubt I have regarding the definitions so I'll like to understand it by some examples I thought of by my own. It might seem trivial to some of you but I am having trouble understanding it.
Suppose $a_{n}$ is a sequence of positive reals such that
$$a_{n}\leq \frac{n}{2^{n^{x}}}+n^{x}$$ for all $x>0$. Can we conclude that $a_{n}=\mathcal{O}(1)$ by saying that $\lim\sup_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n}}{n^{x}}\leq 1$ for each $x>0$ and hence by letting $x\to 0$, we have $a_{n}=\mathcal{O}(1)$?
I am having trouble in saying whether this is correct or not because if I let $x\to 0$ first and then evaluate $\lim\sup$ wrt $n$, then I get $+\infty$.
Also, suppose that $b_{n}$ is a sequence of positive real numbers such that for any sequence $c_{n}\to\infty$, we have $\frac{b_{n}}{c_{n}}\to 0$. Can we say that $b_{n}=\mathcal{O}(1)$?

No, this is not valid. The fact that $\lim\sup_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{n^x}\leq 1$ for all $x$ just implies that $a_n=n^{o(1)}$, but there are sequences with that property that are unbounded, such as $\log n$.
In fact, this sequence could grow like $\log n$. For any $x$, either $n^x\geq \log_4 n$ or $\frac{n}{2^{n^x}}\geq \sqrt n>\log_4 n$, so $a_n=\log_4 n$ satisfies the property.

If you have some quantities $f,g$ and you say something like $f= \mathcal O(g)$ you always have to add something like "for $x \to 0$" or "for $x \to \infty$" if you are talking about functions or "for $n \to \infty$" if you want to consider the asymptotics of a sequence. The statement $f= \mathcal O(g)$ without one of these does not make sense. Sometimes, this is omitted when it is clear from the context (or at least when the authors believe it to be clear from the context). Let me give you an example:
Take $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ given by $f(x) =x+x^2$. Then we have $f= \mathcal O(x^2)$ for $x \to \infty$ because $\limsup_{x\to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{x^2} = 1$, so the quotient stays bounded
On the other hand, we do NOT have $f= \mathcal O(g)$ as $x \to 0$ since $\frac{f(x)}{x^2}$ tends to $\pm \infty$ as $x \to 0$.
It is however true, that $f=\mathcal O(x)$ for $x \to 0$. In that case we even have $f= \mathcal o(x)$ since the quotient $\frac{f(x)}{x}$ tends to zero as $x \to 0$.
Now considering your examples: For the first one we certainly have $a_n = \mathcal O(1)$ as $x \to \infty$ for every single $n$, since $\lim_{x \to 0} a_n = \frac n2 +1 <\infty$. However, if you want to have a uniform statement, you would not be able to say $a_n = \mathcal O(1)$ uniformly in $n$ because the constants tend to infinity.
On the other hand, the statement that $\limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{n^x} \le 1$ means that $a_n = \mathcal O(n^x)$ as $n \to \infty$ (this is a statement about the asymptotics of $a_n$ for a fixed $x$).
As to your second example: saying that $b_n = \mathcal O(1)$ as $n \to \infty$ (which I assume was what you meant) means that $\limsup_{n \to \infty} b_n <\infty$ which just means that $b_n$ is a bounded sequence. So the question is: If for any sequence $c_n \to \infty$ we have $\frac{b_n}{c_n} \to 0$, is $(b_n)_n$ a bounded sequence? This is true, since if $b_n$ was not bounded, there would be a subsequence of $b_n$ which is unbounded and can be arranged to be increasing to $+ \infty$ (or decreasing to $-\infty$) and then we could just take $c_n$ to be the same numbers as the subsequence of $b_n$ for the corresponding indices and something else for the other numbers and we would have $\frac{b_n}{c_n} \to 1$ along a subsequence, which implies that the quotient does not converge to $0$.
